# Order by value in timeseries mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, aggregation-framework

I have a timeseries collection like this ( mongodb documentation sample)

```
_id: "20101010/site-1/apache_pb.gif",
    metadata: {
        date: ISODate("2000-10-10T00:00:00Z"),
        site: "site-1",
        page: "/apache_pb.gif" },
    daily: 5468426,
    hourly: {
        "0": 227850,
        "1": 210231,
        "2" : 12344,
        "23": 20457 },
    minute: {
        "0": 3612,
        "1": 3241,
        ...
        "1439": 2819 }
```

what is the best solution, using aggregation framework, to sort for value of hourly ? so for example I want to order from the lower to higher in hourly in order to have something like this :

```
{
 "2": 12344,
 "23" : 20457,
 "1" : 21031,
"0" : 227850
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Is possible to change your document structure ?

Comment: why not :) , what you suggest? thx

Comment: In all honesty. This is probably one of **"the broadest"** topics you can ever breach on MongoDB. Basically "storing timeseries data". It is "very" opinionated. There are "various" different ways to approach how you do it. You can either "pre-aggregate" on inserts, "post-aggregate" on background jobs, or both. To ask a **real** question here you **need** to give "specifics" about what you are doing. I'm just going to prefix this with @yogesh is not the right person to answer or even attempt to do so based on what I have seen here. Very, very broad. Thin it out if you can.

Comment: @NeilLunn same problem occurred for me so I tried to change my documents structure and solved my issues I think it may be helpful for this person, so I write below my documents structure and aggregation query and I know this is very common and broadest question

Comment: @NeilLunn thx , I'm writing more informations about my request.

Comment: @yogesh thanks for you support . I think that share your experience could be an interesting starting point for me .

Comment: So my point is **"for both of you"** will you either submit your own "exactly what I want to do" question or will @yogesh do exactly the same? Because right now your both saying " I think I want this or maybe that" and you're both so "grey" on this that is is no wonder why you have no guidance on "how to actually do it". Kind of where I basically sit. Rather than "hang around" on StackOverflow and vote up "me too" for topics you don't know how to resolve. Spend some effort to **explain you problem properly**. If you review, I'm one of the few people here who makes the effort, when you do.

Comment: *@NeilLunn: I beg your pardon, but I have to intervene.* I have to second Neil here. Simply dropping in requirements and asking how to best solve them is __not__ the scope of SO. Modelling data and how to access it is __strongly__ use case specific, has a lot to do with the business cases and can't be answered after a short text. Actually, there are consultants for this, charging quite some money *because they put a lot of time and effort into answering such questions.* If you have problems *implementing* **your** solution, SO is the place to ask.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg. You can easily "oversimplify" here or look at the "bigger picture". I would strongly suggest to all to at least take a look at a reference model put together by MongoDB Consulting staff. https://github.com/10gen-labs/hvdf. Kind of wraps up various possibilities in an solution that in 'service configuarable' to what you want to do with the data. Code more than a "snippet" gives a better perspective on the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this same problem occurred for me then that time I changed my documents structure as below 
`{
    "_id" : "20101010/site-1/apache_pb.gif",
    "metadata" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2000-10-10T00:00:00Z"),
        "site" : "site-1",
        "page" : "/apache_pb.gif"
    },
    "daily" : 5468426,
    "hourly" : [
        {
            "hour" : 0,
            "value" : 227850
        },
        {
            "hour" : 1,
            "value" : 210231
        },
        {
            "hour" : 2,
            "value" : 12344
        },
        {
            "hour" : 23,
            "value" : 20457
        }
    ],
    "minute" : [
        {
            "min" : 0,
            "value" : 3612
        },
        {
            "min" : 1,
            "value" : 3241
        },
        {
            "min" : 1439,
            "value" : 2819
        }
    ]
}`

And in your case you want to sort hourly data according to values from lower to highest first so I write following aggregation query which may be solve your problem

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
                        {"$unwind":"$hourly"},
                       {"$project":{"hour":"$hourly.hour","value":"$hourly.value"}},  
                      {"$sort":{"hour":-1}},
                     {"$group":{"_id":0,"hourlyData":
                    {"$push":  {"hour":"$hour","value":"$value"}}}}).pretty()
```

Comment: @Neil Lunn I solved my documents structure problem using creating above documents

Comment: At which point are you going to realize that I am not "insulting" you, but just making an oberservation that your personal level of experience is very lacking in trying to advise others. It's a free forum to do so, but maybe you just shouldn't when you approaches as so misleading and wrong.

Comment: @NeilLunn how you think my **personal level of experience is very lacking in trying to advise others** I am just telling that user how same problem I solved, I am not forcing to user to implement same thing which I implemented

Comment: It's just not **the definitive solution**. You have to admit as well you have more "answers" submitted on here that "acceptances" and not by a small margin. I for one do not want people to follow "your example" because it is not the **one way to do it**. The topic **very very broad** as I have suggested. Please Understand that I am contributing here basically because the "standard" was very low. All to happy to promote high quality answers. But there are few of them, and the standard is still low. If you cannot format code properly, then you should not be teaching. Bad blocks, scrolling text.

Comment: Hi NeilLunn and yogesh, my request was just an attempt to share a problem and get feedback from someone about possible solutions. Yogesh , thank you for sharing your experience and also NeilLunn for to have focus on the importance of the skills , even if the formatting (my personal opinion :D ) is not an indication of competence. Thanks again! good week